# 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes, reshape

Here is my code:

```
train_images = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  '/content/drive/MyDrive/ArabicHandwritten2/train')

train_labels = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  '/content/drive/MyDrive/ArabicHandwritten2/test')

train_images = tf.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 256, 256, 3).astype('float32')
train_images = (train_images - 127.5) / 127.5 # Normalize the images to [-1, 1]

BUFFER_SIZE = 16765
BATCH_SIZE = 32

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_images).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

How can I solve the error?
Thanks.

Comment: Could we see the whole traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Because `image_dataset_from_directory` returns a `tf.data.Dataset` which has no `shape` attribute. And you can see how to use the `tf.reshape` function [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape):